# Creating a Styled Text and Number Floating Over a PNG Image in CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to create a triko using CSS. I have an image of a jersey and would like to write a jersey number with a text inside this image.
However, how do I do that best?
What is the best way to insert the number and name into the image? I have tried, but it does not look so optimal and good.

```css
.jersy {
  
}

.number {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -350px;
  margin-left: 256px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -256px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jersy">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/941/941480.png"/>
  <div class="number">
   10
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Frank
  </div>
</div>
```

[Image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3ONb.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO!  If you found my answer helpful, feel free to mark it correct to help others.  If not, please let me know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you are placing elements on top of or behind other elements, you should set your [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) attribute in CSS.  For what you're trying to do, I recommend using `absolute`.  From the MDN webdocs link...

> The **position** CSS property sets how an element is positioned in a document.

In addition, you forgot to set `margin-left` and `font-size` on the `.text` style.

```css
.jersy {
  
}

.number {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -350px;
  margin-left: 256px;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -256px;
  margin-left: 256px;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="jersy">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/941/941480.png"/>
  <div class="number">
   10
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Frank
  </div>
</div>
```